# Minimum space to allocate for Windows System Restore points

Tags: windows-7, windows, disk-space, system-restore

I'm using Win7 and am wondering what is the minimum space that is recommended to allocate for the System Restore function.
It's currently (by default) set to 7.5 GB which seems an awful lot.

How much should be set to allow it to save 1 or 2 points by default, would 500MB - 1GB be enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The amount is dependent on the software actually installed on your computer. With time it will increase, as registry fragmentation sets in.

It's a good idea not to minimize the allocation too much, since the ability to go back a week might sometime save your skin (I mean the computer's).

The simplest way to calculate how much space you need *at the moment*, is to calculate the total disk space taken by the restore points and divide it by their number.

Here's how to calculate this on Vista (and probably Win7):
[How To Reduce Disk Space Used By Windows Vista System Restore](http://www.watchingthenet.com/how-to-reduce-disk-space-used-by-windows-vista-system-restore.html)

For XP see:
[Windows XP System Restore Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](http://www.5starsupport.com/faq/xp-system-restore.htm#1-10)

Answer (score 2):

The amount used by a restore point is dependent on what changes led to its creation. I'm not aware of any hard or fast rule. The more space you give it, the more restore points it can hold.
If you need the space more than you need restore points, you can even turn it off completely. Personally i'd leave it alone and get another hard disk.

Comment: "The more space you give it, the more restore points it can hold" my point exactly, what would be an average to hold 1 or 2 points only?

Comment: Depends what you do. I've seen 15MB restore points, and 1.5GB ones too, on the same machine.